# nativescript, angular2 and heaththkit - HKHealthStore not found;

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am trying to follow the docs at https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-iOS-HealthKit which lets face it is poorly documented... tsk tsk tsk

I have healthkit enabled in my xcode project.

Per this sample https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-iOS-HealthKit/blob/master/app/components/main/main.ts file I am trying to import:

```
var healthStore: HKHealthStore; 

cant find name HKHealthStore
```

How to I import properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That sample 2 years old, from the very early days of NativeScript. Looks like the platform type definitions were part of tns_modules back then, so that's why the project has them on board (look for `HKHealthStore` in https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NativeScript/sample-iOS-HealthKit/master/app/tns_modules/ios.d.ts).

You'll need to add this plugin and follow the instructions to get HealthKit typings and code completion in your project: https://www.npmjs.com/package/tns-platform-declarations

Comment: left me more confused.  Is there not a guide to work with healtkit?

Comment: HealthKit is just a built-in iOS SDK, so it works like accessing any other native API in NativeScript. To make life easier you can add typings for the native SDK and that's what I thought you needed. If you need more general help on how HealthKit needs to be used, either study Apple's SDK docs (they're really quite good) or look at how I've implemented the Cordova plugin: https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/HealthKit